# Terminal MacOS - terminal and "Press [c] to configure"

Tags: macos, terminal, cmake

I have a problem with Mac and the terminal. I need to compile a program. Xcode and command line tools are installed. After `cmake` one needs to press `c` to configure and then `g` to generate the makefile. Well, my problem is - how do I enter the command "c" into terminal? 
Forgive me if this is super-simple, but I am new to Mac, fairly new to source codes and the combination is difficult...

Best, 
Peter

Comment: Have you tried pressing the `c` key on your keyboard?  What happens when you do?

Comment: Yes, first thing I did, as one would expect..nothing. Also c+enter yields unknown command.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the situation where you're asked to press `c`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solution: $ccmake. Then $ ccmake c (directory) and $ ccmake g (directory)